# c-lightning public node data on explorers

Tags: lightning-network

I'm trying to set my first clightning node with docker-compose using image from https://hub.docker.com/r/elementsproject/lightningd. Currently, my node can connect and open channel with other nodes (and I can open a channel to the node just fine), but it's still not updated (ie. has no information) on most explorers.

I've tried to make my port `9735` open, set the `bind-addr` as the docker's IP address, even tried to set `announce-addr` with tor addresses. Nothing works.

The following is current results of `getinfo` and `listconfigs`:

```
getinfo
{
   "id": "03db40337c2de299a8fa454fdf89d311615d50a27129d43286696d9e497b2b027a",
   "alias": "TestName",
   "color": "fff000",
   "num_peers": 3,
   "num_pending_channels": 0,
   "num_active_channels": 3,
   "num_inactive_channels": 0,
   "address": [
      {
         "type": "ipv4",
         "address": "68.183.195.14",
         "port": 9735
      }
   ],
   "binding": [
      {
         "type": "ipv4",
         "address": "172.18.0.3",
         "port": 9735
      }
   ],
   "version": "v0.7.1-906-gf657146",
   "blockheight": 601917,
   "network": "bitcoin",
   "msatoshi_fees_collected": 0,
   "fees_collected_msat": "0msat"
}

listconfigs    
{
   "# version": "v0.7.1-906-gf657146",
   "lightning-dir": "/root/.lightning",
   "wallet": "sqlite3:///root/.lightning/lightningd.sqlite3",
   "plugin": "/usr/local/bin/../libexec/c-lightning/plugins/pay",
   "plugin": "/usr/local/bin/../libexec/c-lightning/plugins/autoclean",
   "plugin": "/usr/local/bin/../libexec/c-lightning/plugins/fundchannel",
   "network": "bitcoin",
   "allow-deprecated-apis": true,
   "always-use-proxy": false,
   "daemon": "false",
   "rpc-file": "lightning-rpc",
   "rgb": "fff000",
   "alias": "HubTest",
   "bitcoin-rpcuser": [redacted],
   "bitcoin-rpcpassword": [redacted],
   "bitcoin-rpcconnect": "bitcoind",
   "bitcoin-retry-timeout": 60,
   "pid-file": "lightningd-bitcoin.pid",
   "ignore-fee-limits": false,
   "watchtime-blocks": 144,
   "max-locktime-blocks": 2016,
   "funding-confirms": 3,
   "commit-fee-min": 200,
   "commit-fee-max": 2000,
   "commit-fee": 500,
   "cltv-delta": 14,
   "cltv-final": 10,
   "commit-time": 10,
   "fee-base": 0,
   "rescan": 15,
   "fee-per-satoshi": 1,
   "max-concurrent-htlcs": 30,
   "min-capacity-sat": 10000,
   "bind-addr": "172.18.0.3:9735",
   "announce-addr": "68.183.195.14:9735",
   "offline": "false",
   "autolisten": true,
   "disable-dns": "false",
   "enable-autotor-v2-mode": "false",
   "encrypted-hsm": false,
   "log-level": "DEBUG",
   "log-prefix": "lightningd(7):"
}
```

Is there something wrong with this configuration? Or, is it another issue after all?

I understand that explorers update their node list irregularly, and as far as the node can open channels (and can be connected), everything is fine. but this thing has bugging me for weeks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

updated the docker image and put `bind-addr` to `0.0.0.0:9375` somehow fixed the problem for some unknown reason.